# Highlight user selected text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with someone else's code, and if I change too much, it breaks. 
I need to highlight a portion of text that a user has highlighted.
It needs to be highlighted based on the ID of that element and not on the actual text. If it is based on the actual text, it will highlight every instance of that text and I only want the instance the user selected. I have been beating my head for a week now trying to figure out how to edit this code so that it will do what I need it to do. Can anyone help me figure out what I need to edit in order to get this accomplished?

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
// Name: doHighlight()
// Find all occurences of the search term in the given text,
// and add some "highlight" tags to them (we're not using a
// regular expression search, because we want to filter out
// matches that occur within HTML tags and script blocks, so
// we have to do a little extra validation)
//-------------------------------------------------------
function doHighlight(bodyText, searchTerm, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag)
{
    var newText = "";
    var i = -1;
    var lcSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    var lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();
    var temp = 0;
    var counter = 0;

//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************
//Here is the ID of the <p> element where our text was selected
    alert(textId);
//Here is the text of the ID of the <p> element we selected
     alert(document.getElementById(textId).innerHTML);
//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************

    while (bodyText.length > 0)
    {
        i = lcBodyText.indexOf(lcSearchTerm, i++);

        if (i < 0)
    {
        newText += bodyText;
        bodyText = "";
    }
    else
    {
        // skip anything inside an HTML tag
         if (bodyText.lastIndexOf(">", i) >= bodyText.lastIndexOf("<", i))
        {
            // skip anything inside a <script> block
            if (lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("/script>", i) >= lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("<script", i))
            {   
//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************
// Writes the document til it reaches the search term, then adds highlightStartTag then the search term then highlightEndTag
// Then writes more of the document until the search term is reached again 
// Needs to search for the term based on the id="" given to the <p> element
// Then add the highlightStartTag and highlightEndTag
                newText += bodyText.substring(0, i) + highlightStartTag + bodyText.substr(i, searchTerm.length) + highlightEndTag;
                bodyText = bodyText.substr(i + searchTerm.length); 
                lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();
                i = +1;
//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************
//********************************************************************
                }
            }
        }
        //break;
    }
    //newText += bodyText;
    return newText;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: so the user selects some text, and you then want that particular selected text to be highlighted?

Comment: We add a little icon to the side of that <p> element. and that works great, but if the user highlights "Tools and tips" then it puts the little icon next to each instance of "Tools and tips".  We only want to put the icon next to that instance the user selected.  So I need to modify this code to add the highlightStartTag and EndTag to the <p> element based on the <p> element's ID.

Comment: What is that little icon why dont  you use jsfiddle to explain your problem , so that we can easily help you out

Comment: I would love to use jfiddle to explain but there is entirely too much code for me to do that.  I cannot show most of the info that I would need to in order to accomplish that.  Plus jsfiddle does not have enough room.

Comment: Well I tried jsfiddle, but I cannot get it to work. Works just fine in dreamweaver though.  But here is essentially the same thing.  I edited this so each paragraph has an ID associated with it to help emphasize what I am trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/xRuhRohx/85sdq/

Comment: I've updated your jsFiddle (my example uses jQuery, just for speed of coding): http://jsfiddle.net/66fK3/ now when you click the button, the prompt appears. Can you explain step-by-step exactly what should happen when a user clicks the button?

Comment: Thank you for getting that jsfiddle working. Clicking the button should retrieve the <p> element's ID, and then highlight the text the user selected based on that ID.  There are several instances of "search term" in the text.  If the user selects "search term" from the first <p> element, I only want it to highlight "search term" in the first <p> element, not the whole body.

Comment: Where is the button getting the <p>'s ID from? If a user types text into the box, they could type something that matches almost anything on the page, multiple times...

Comment: The person before me used most of the code from the jsfiddle i posted for searching for the text.  The ID is trimmed out in another part of the .js file.  That is why my code above, I pulled in the ID and placed it into the textId variable.  So it is there, but I just need to know how to fix the doHighlight function so it puts the highlightStartTag and EndTag around the <p> element of the selected text.

Comment: So you're OK with it highlighting more than one paragraph?

Comment: No, just the paragraph that the word is in that the user selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you need, but it might be enough to get you started; I've managed to augment the code so that instead of a generic `<font>` tag, the search term is highlighted with a `<span>` tag with a class of `.hilite`. The script then searches for the first occurrence of that span tag, and sets the parent's ID as a variable (`firstParent`).

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/66fK3/5/)

The example uses jQuery, so you could refer to the parent element like this:

```
$('#' + firstParent).before('<img src="myicon.png" />');
```

This would insert an icon before the containing parent.

You can use this as a jumping-on point to augment the script to your needs. You should probably build in an extra layer of error-checking, in case the search term isn't found, or the parent element doesn't have an ID...

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am not quite sure how to implement this though.  The code this guy wrote is a mess and I have managed to find, and fix 5 other issues that were requested of me.  This text highlight issue is my last issue to resolve.  Then I will be able to write all my own code from here on out.

Comment: OK, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/66fK3/7/ it adds a 'hilite' span to all occurrences of the search term, then wraps the parent's contents in a span tag with the styling applied. This, in effect, highlights the whole parent tag. You can achieve the same thing by restyling the parent tag itself. If you want to cascade back up the document (say, to find the immediate p tag) take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: Updated jsFiddle which only affects parent p tags... http://jsfiddle.net/66fK3/8/ (note that this will fire on all occurrences of the word on the page; if the search term occurs in more than one paragraph, the background of all of those paragraphs will change colour)

Comment: I really appreciate the input.  jsfiddle is not opening for me at the moment, but I will let you know as soon as it does and if this works for me.  Again, thank you much.

Comment: No problem - yeah, jsFiddle was being a bit shaky for me when I was updating the code. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you :)

Comment: Stupid, me. Let me update this process with some info. After the user selects the text, and it trims the tags off, it gets put into an xml file.  the text that the user selected is pulled out of the xml file and then searched for to find placement of the highlight icon.  I have added the ID to the xml file, so it could be used later.  I don't know if that changes how my question is answered.  I am still waiting on jsfiddle to work.  :-(